# XML 'Element' object has no attribute 'find' (python)

Tags: python, xml, text, printing, xml-parsing

I really just want to find the body value in this simple xml code:

```
<question id="3">
    <body>hello world</body>
</question>
```

I'm using this code:

```
for thing in doc.getElementsByTagName('question'):
    print(thing.find('body').text)
```

I would assume that it'd print "hello world", but it doesn't. Any help will be really, really appreciated as I've been trying to fix this for 45 minutes, going through literally every single post I could find of it and I still can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using this code:

```
def getText(nodelist):
rc = []
for node in nodelist:
    if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
        rc.append(node.data)
    else:
        rc.append(getText(node.childNodes))
return ''.join(rc)

for thing in doc.getElementsByTagName('question'):
    question = getText(qthing.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].childNodes)
    print(question)
```